# Is there a good and bad kind of soreness after exercise?

Tags: muscle-soreness

I vaguely remember being told that there are two kind of soreness after exercise, one indicate good things (e.g. your muscle is being trained) and the other bad (e.g. you didn't warm up or cool down properly), and both have their fancy name and acronyms.

Is such distinction accurate? Do they differ in a way that I can notice, e.g. can I tell by the duration, the "feel", or the location of the soreness?

Answer (score 1):

"Good" Pain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_onset_muscle_soreness

"Bad" Pain: **It is hard to quantify.** But for me, when you hurt the muscle or ligaments, it feels more stiff. It is a lot more sore in a way that will make you flinch when touched, and you will try very hard not to put any significant strain on the muscle.

For example, just this morning I pulled my upper back doing some bad snatches. My neck is stiff and sore, and I can clearly tell the difference from this, and the DOMS I have in my thighs from squatting heavy two days ago. My legs might be sore when I walk up or down stairs, or when I biked to work, but it doesn't "hurt" in the same way my neck does.